# Upgrade from 14.04.4 to 16.04.1 LTS with do-release-upgrade doesn't offer new version when run with sudo

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, lts

Why do-release-upgrade doesn't offer me new version (16.04.1 from 14.04) when is runned as

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

whilst when I run it as normal user it start download new version (after giving user password)?
Will the second way upgrade system correctly?
Thank you for answer

Comment: Your question does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with rubbish in files contained in directory:

```
/var/lib/update-manager
```

as are

- meta-release-lts
- meta-release-lts-development

They contained some nonsense information but their modification attributes were later then web version of these files so they weren't downloaded.
For common user it worked because files from directory

```
~/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release-lts
```

were used.
Solution: delete files in directory /var/lib/update-manager (backup it before!!!).